# How to replace first 7 digit in sql

Tags: mysql

I want to replace the first 7 digits of **shg_uid** with the **block_id** column value in my SQL

```
block_id    shg_uid
2727010 27270010001
2727010 27270010003
2727010 27270010004
2711006 27110040001
2711006 27110040002
2711006 27110040003
2711006 27110040004
2726021 27260110001
```

**Required Output**

```
block_id    shg_uid
2727010 27270100001
2727010 27270100003
2727010 27270100004
2711006 27110060001
2711006 27110060002
2711006 27110060003
2711006 27110060004
2726021 27260210001
```

Comment: I think you should rethink this. Just store 1,3,4,1,2,3,4,1 for the shg_id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try  using string manipulation ..

```
select concat( bloock_id,right(sgh_uid, length(shg_id) -7)) 
from my_table
```

and for update

```
Update my_table  
set shg_id = concat( bloock_id,right(sgh_uid, length(shg_id) -7))
```

Comment: *`right(sgh_uid, length(shg_id) -7)`* Better `SUBSTRING(sgh_uid FROM 8)`.

Comment: @Akina  right but I came up with right and length first